# how to get translation database in ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode4

I am making a language translation app for iPhone. Just wanted to ask how to get the translation database for different langauges? I am sure one can't manually enter each and every word of so many languages! Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just refer the link contains the little database, it may useful:

[http://www.omegawiki.org/Help:Downloading_the_data](http://www.omegawiki.org/Help%3aDownloading_the_data)

http://glosbe.com/about

http://www.dicts.info/uddl.php

If not found in this database, Just go with translator and store that word in your database.In feature it will retrive the word from your database for that particular word.

Comment: thanks the page seems really useful but I am getting confused on how to use it? Is there any tutorial for that?

Comment: for http://glosbe.com/about use this api http://glosbe.com/a-api. and for this http://www.omegawiki.org/Help:Downloading_the_data download the that file and import that into your db, that will guide you well.

Comment: Sir can you please provide me with a tutorial on using glosbe api? It would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Localization on iOS is done through using a macro...

```
NSLocalizedString(@"The string", @"Description");
```

You can then generate the translation files for the app using a terminal tool called `genstrings`.

The final translation though is just a case of going through these files and translating the text.

You can read more about it on [Ray Wenderlich's Site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014).

I'd also recommend this site as a good start for a lot of iOS things.

Comment: wouldn't localization convert the whole text of the app in another langauge? how would I just translate the text entered by the user in the text field?

Comment: or would it be better if I ask how to localize only a string ?

Comment: Ah, in that case you want to use a translation service like @BulletRaja suggested. There's no way you're going to be able to store all possible words in a DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use various API  which is made for Translation . Like Google,Mygengo,Microsoft traslation API,WebServiceX Translate API.

Comment: which one out of these would be the most useful and free? because google one is paid service now.